# jQuery script has to be run after ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery in one of my velocity macro template  (i.e. content footer which will be loaded the last).

This script works in all the pages except one page. On that page, after the page is completely rendered, a *table is inserted in the middle of the page*. So I tried with onload function, still no luck.

```
<table id="ArtifactListTable" class="ItemListTable"> 
<!-- this table is inserted after ajax     request -->

<script>
  window.onload = function() { 
     jQuery('.priority1').text('P1');
     jQuery('.priority2').text('P2');
     jQuery('.priority3').text('P3');
     jQuery('.priority4,.priority5').text('None');

     jQuery('.priority4,.priority5').addClass('priority0').removeClass('priority4 priority5');
  };

</script>
```

I need to **run my jQuery after this AJAX load function** (I have no control over ajax). I can only deal with my jQuery.

Comment: share how the ajax load is used to load the table

Comment: JQuery ajax calls have a 'success' callback - supply a function that does the above and set it as the success callback function for your ajax call.

Comment: If you can get access to the jqXHR object returned by the jQuery Ajax call (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), then you can attach a .done() function to it which will be run after it has completed (or use .always() if you want to run it even if it fails).

Answer (score 4):

If the ajax call is done by some plugin which has no `callbacks`, you could use jQuerys `ajaxComplete` handler and do things depending on the requests `URL` etc.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {
  //check XMLHttpRequest and do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: //your URL,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (d) {//pur your script here 
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if the table is loaded using `.load()`, then make use of the load callback as given below

```
$('<someel>').load('url', function(){
    jQuery('.priority1').text('P1');
    jQuery('.priority2').text('P2');
    jQuery('.priority3').text('P3');
    jQuery('.priority4,.priority5').text('None');

    jQuery('.priority4,.priority5').addClass('priority0').removeClass('priority4 priority5');

})
```

Comment: Thanks arun for your reply I alraedy tried with the table-id load likejQuery('#ArtifactListTable').load(function() {

}); but not expected output Is there anything we check through jquery to check any ajax request and run jquery after that ajax call is complete

Answer (score 0):

jQuery GET or POST. Third parameter calls after success AJAX call.

```
$.get("url", {json: "get"}, function(result){
  $("#content").html(result);
  // DO SOME CODE
})
```